# I need to normalize this distribution, but cannot identify it

Tags: distributions, data-transformation

[image: Density]

[image: Q-Q Plot]

I have this distribution that I need to normalize for comparison between sub-populations. I thought it might be lognormal, but the kurtosis of the log product is still very high.

How do I go about normalizing this data, through either transforming it to the normal distribution or by working with it directly. I would like to end up with a z-score like number I can apply to individual observations.

Comment: You subtract the sample mean and then divide by the sample standard deviation: $z_i = \dfrac{x_i-\bar{x}}{\sigma}$. What's the problem with that?

Comment: I would like to replicate the proportionality of the z-score under a normal distribution i.e that 95% of data is within the -2 : 2 range etc.

Comment: What about empirical quantiles?

Comment: You mean, given the value of observation X what empirical quantile of the total population does it belong to? That could work...

Comment: What is your goal? You say *for comparison between sub-populations*, why not ask directly about that, with enogh context for an answer?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I think I was stuck on two separate questions. On the one hand how comparison between sub-populations and on the other what distribution this is. As for my main question the empirical quantiles was sufficient for comparisons